# Best way to enforce custom coding standards for a developer

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My requirement is to design a framework to enforce custom coding standards (per Gitlab project) pre-push or while raising an MR. We are looking at Gitlab CI/ Webhooks / Server-side githooks.
We faced resistance from Gitlab admins that Server-side githooks are not the right way as it may result in a server overload and lead to Gitlab performance issues.
Also, we want to give the developer the choice to commit with or without fixing the issues that crop up after the check (in case of emergency situations). The check should happen on the server side and not at the client-side (developer). The applications may be backend/front-end with technologies like Java/ReactJS/NodeJS etc.
**What would be the best way to implement this?**

Comment: I would recommend rewriting this question to avoid opinion-based responses.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have a build stage that runs a linter for your language, and have it fail if the code doesn't meet the standards.

Then enforce rules so that all merges to master must go through a merge request, and all build stages must pass before a request can be approved.